# Getting IDispatch interface pointer for running application (e.g. Excel)

Tags: c++, c, vba, com

Suppose I can write (in pseudocode)

```
ptr = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

And doing that creates an instance of excel.exe and gives me the dispatch pointer for the Excel.Application interface.

Is there any way I can get the dispatch pointer for an instance of excel that is currently running? C++ code would be preferred, but VBA (via Windows API), C and Java are good too as I can always port.

Comment: Like VBA's GetObject? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288902

Comment: C++ code is [`GetActiveObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: For C++, they show the code [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238610/en-us).

Comment: @Alex K. Hey that's clever. Concerningly I've read about that a number of years ago. Can I achieve that using windows API? Please put as an answer and I'll certainly +1 and accept.

Comment: @RomanR linked it with OLE's `GetActiveObject`

Comment: FYI, to check what active object are currently running you can use [`RotView`](http://alax.info/blog/1444), a former SDK `irotview` clone.